# gmail api from issue

Tags: php, curl, gmail, gmail-api

I am able to send emails via gmail api without any errors but even if I have from header with name (i.e From: < Dummy name > dummy@gmail.com) when email is delivered it shows only email address and not the name.

Code I am using:

```
$url= "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send";
$header = array('Content-Type: message/rfc822', "Authorization: Bearer $access_token");

        $from = "<$user_name> $user_email";
        $line = "\r\n";
        $raw = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".$line;
        $raw .= "To: $to ".$line;
        $raw .= "from: $from".$line;
        $raw .= "Reply-To: $user_email".$line;
        $raw .= "subject: $subject".$line.$line;
        //$raw .= "Reply-To: $user_email".$line;
        $raw .= $message;

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    if( $header !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if( $data !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Try `Name <email>`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. silly mistake. :)